# Android catch Bluetooth HFP's Activate Voice Recognition

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition

When Bluetooth hands free device connected to mobile phone, if device sends an AT command **AT+BVRA** to enable voice recognition, the mobile phone launches the default voice recognition app if it supports.

My android phone (OS : 4.1.2, Model : Samsung Galaxy Core I8262) launching **S Voice** app for recognition.

I think if my phone has more recognition activities, it may show list to select one, if no default set. I never observed this case.

My question, **Is there any way to catch AT+BVRA command received ?**

If anybody know about this, please give your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To receive AT+BVRA on Android, you need to grab the VOICE_COMMAND intent. This is what you need in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

On Samsung phones, the priority for S-Voice is set high (10, if I recall correctly). This means that no application will get this intent. You need to disable S-Voice: ([Instructions on how to disable apps](http://www.androidcentral.com/everything-you-wanted-know-about-disabling-apps-your-android)) to receive the intent.