# Blocking Google Assistant during a bluetooth headset initiated voice recognition session?

Tags: audio-recording, android-bluetooth, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, headset

I'm working on a voice recognition app that connects to custom hardware using a bluetooth handsfree profile (HFP aka headset profile) connection.  The application is used to pass PCM audio data to a cloud based voice recognition server, by leveraging the Android AudioRecord class.  This functionality works fine if the application initiates the SCO connection, but if the headset hardware initiates the SCO connection, by issuing the AT+BVRA HFP command to the phone, Google Assistant always hijacks the phone.  Thus, my question is how can I stop this?  Is there a way to programmatically tell Google Assistant to chill?  I've tried many different things (AudioManager sco management, AudioRouting preferred connection, BluetoothHeadset profile class, Java Reflection & View.setAssitBlocked(true), etc...), but none of them seem able to either block Google Assistant or recapture the SCO connection.  (It also seems that the handset opens up an A2DP for google assistant's audio feed).  I'm hoping this is possible with a Java based solution... ?

Answer (score -1):

[As noted by another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250547/2718941), what is likely happening is that Android is broadcasting an [ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND), and since Google Assistant is set up to receive it, it gets priority on the connection.  Your app could register for the intent and see if it gets priority on receiving it.